# Flink create table via table DSL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

In order to create table, I use an SQL syntax like

```
    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings)
    tableEnv.executeSql(
      "CREATE TABLE asset (smth STRING) " +
        "WITH ('connector' = 'jdbc', " +
        "'url' = 'jdbc:mysql://host:3306/db', " +
        "'username' = 'user', " +
        "'password' = 'pass', " +
        "'table-name' = 'table')"
    )
```

Is there an option to define a table via Table API DSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the very same table with the following Table API methods:

```
    Schema schema =
            Schema.newBuilder()
                    .column("smth", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .build();
    TableDescriptor tableDescriptor =
            TableDescriptor.forConnector("jdbc")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.URL, "jdbc:mysql://host:3306/db")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.USERNAME, "user")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.PASSWORD, "pass")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.TABLE_NAME, "table")
                    .schema(schema)
                    .build();
    tEnv.createTable("asset", tableDescriptor);
```

To create a temporary table instead, use `tEnv.createTemporaryTable`.

Check [`TableDescriptor`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/api/TableDescriptor.Builder.html) and [`Schema`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/api/Schema.Builder.html) for more details.

Comment: what is the difference between `createTable` vs `createTemporaryTable` in nutshell?
I use this JDBC connector to initial load data from DB. ( see my comment under David's answer)

Comment: `createTable` adds the table to the catalog, while `createTemporaryTable` adds the table only to the existing session. Catalogs are metadata stores that you can use to retain your metadata about sql objects (tables, functions, views) etc, storing them and reusing it across several Flink SQL applications. For more details https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/catalogs/

For prototyping, just use temporary tables, but once you want to create a production setup, a catalog is something you might need to handle metadata.

Comment: currently I use jdbc only to load some initial data from external DB. no needs to access any db metadata.
in that case there is a sense to use temporary tables? in terms of performance

Comment: Temporary and permanent tables have nothing to do with runtime performance, it's just a matter of how you wanna manage metadata. If you don't need a centralized metadata store for Flink SQL tables, using temporary tables is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is remove these table definitions from your code and store them in a persistent catalog. But for creating temporary tables in the in-memory catalog, what you're doing is how it's done.

Comment: actually I use TableAPI to load some data from MySQL DB (there's few tables I need to join) -> convert it into regular DataStream -> put it into flink state
what is the most effective way to do that?